# How do I use ASP.NET Core Identity to authenticate and authorize users with credentials stored in Cosmos Db (Blazor Server)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

I have a Blazor Server app that contains a client-side and an admin side. I would like to create a login page that grants access to the admin pages.

I know that I need to use ASP.NET Core Identity, but I do not know how to make it work with a Cosmos DB database.

Could anyone please provide the additional steps I need to follow that are different from a solution that makes use of a SQL Server database?

From what I can see, a lot of it is the same but my issue lies with the additional steps needed to get this to work with Cosmos DB.

Many thanks!

Comment: This article shows how to configure to run under managed identities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-managed-identity The articles below that one also show how to configure data access/RBAC. And this sample shows how to implement auth-z in your code. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-db-nosql-dotnet-samples/tree/main/002-quickstart-passwordless